# call_user_func_array for dynamic mysqli_bind_param

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to bind a dynamic number of values to mysqli_bind_params function using call_user_func_array, it seems to be working in the way i'd expect, but it still seems to be calling the first value as an array instead of a string. Any thoughts, it throws out this error.

```
 mysqli_stmt::bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in <b>/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Tests/functions.php</b> on line 

function insertUsers($db, $keys, $vals){

 //temprorarily replacing the $vals with the array $values
   $values = array('test','test');
   $stmt=$db->prepare("INSERT INTO users ($keys) VALUES (?,?)"); 
   $paramTypes=array('s');
   $inputArray[] = &$paramTypes;
   $j = count($values);
   for($i=0;$i<$j;$i++){
     $inputArray[] = &$values[$i];
     print_r($inputArray);
     call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $inputArray);
 }
     $stmt->execute();
     $stmt->close();

}
```

I have also tried using call_user_func_array, but then it returns another error.
call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, first array member is not a valid class name or object in **/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Tests/functions.php**

Comment: `$paramTypes=array('s');` should not be an array, but a simple string: `$paramTypes='s';`

Comment: where $keys are coming from?

Comment: $listKeys = implode(", ", array_keys($post));
$testdbinput = insertUsers($db, $listKeys, $post);

Comment: I tried that too, but and the error has changed to but then it returns another error. call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, first array member is not a valid class name or object in  $stmt is a valid callback is it not?

Comment: your main problem is a loop, which shouldn't be. Besides, nowadays there is a much simpler way than that ugly call user func

Comment: So your function is vulnerable to sql injection. I have no idea why would you get the field names from POST instead of just hardcoding them in the query

Comment: when I print out input Array the values look right.. are you referring to PDO?

Comment: Just trying different ways to condense code, I could just hardcode them in. But I am using mysqli_prepared statements doesn't that cut down the chance of SQL injection?

Comment: a prepared statement is not a magic want that protects you in a puff of smoke. *Obviously*, it protects only what is put as ? in your query, but a blunt $keys goes in your query as is, open to all and every injection in the world

Comment: Regarding condensing the code, check my recent answer, there are some explanations: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/182528/mysql-flexible-insert-record-with-bind-param-or-bind-value

Comment: Okay Thanks! Can I defined my sql statement as a constant and call it with the fields hardcoded in ?